# Flow of the project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture

I am currently working in java projects. And I am handling many projects at a time. I use `eclipse IDE` for programming these applications which involves spring, hibernate, flex technologies. Every time i work in a new project i would have to take some time analyzing the code flow(which is a tedious and time consuming task). Is there a tool which just creates a doc or flow diagram stating its cohesion and coupling(simply its architecture) when we check out and configure the code base from a `repo` to our local system?

Your thoughts will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try out the TPTP profiler in eclipse. If you start your app in the profiling mode and use it for a while, the profiler plugin will draw for you the interactions between classes which have taken place while you were using the app.

Comment: Will this plugin work for spring and other technologies where xml files are included or just that it reads java files? Please comment.

Comment: I do not run this project in eclipse. Using maven I build the project using eclipse and deploy it in the tomcat server. So i guess I  cannot use this plugin which says it is tightly coupled with eclipse!!!

Comment: The use of the Tomcat web server is not an obstacle here. The same applies to Spring.

Comment: I have recently used this plugin to profile an enterprise app deployed in Glassfish. It wasn't trivial to set up eclipse and the server, but eventually it worked.

Comment: ok. So just to confirm, even if the server is not running from eclipse, the profiler works?

Comment: That's right. You just need to tell the JVM in which the Server runs to allow  JVMPI connections. This article may help you: http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/platform/org.eclipse.tptp.platform.agentcontroller/src-native-new/packaging_md/windows/getting_started.html?root=TPTP_Project&view=co#javaprof